# Not a sub class error

Tags: java

```
import javafx.application.Application;    
import javafx.scene.Scene;    
import javafx.scene.control.Button;   
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;  
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Calc {  

  public class Gui extends Application{  
    @Override  
    public void start(Stage stage){  
        TextField mainText = new TextField();  

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(mainText);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setTitle("Calculator");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
 }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I try to exececute the program I get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class Calc is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:211)
    at Calc.main(Calc.java:56)`

I don't understand how it's not a subclass when the scope of the import is over the Calc class so that means the sub classes of those should be able to use them imports.

Answer (score 6):

> I don't understand how it's not a subclass when the scope of the import is over the Calc class so that means the sub classes of those should be able to use them imports.

Subclassing and imports are *entirely* different things. It's complaining that your `Calc` class is declared as:

```
public class Calc
```

rather than

```
public class Calc extends Application
```

Now your `Gui` class is a subclass of `Application` - but as you can see from the error message, JavaFX isn't trying to launch `Gui`, it's trying to launch `Calc`.

Personally I'd suggest getting rid of the extra class, and *just* having `Calc` extend `Application`, with both the `main` method (for launching) and the `start` method. Alternatively, you could specify the `Gui` class explicitly:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Application.launch(Gui.class, args);
}
```

... but then you'd *also* want to make the `Gui` class `static`, so that it would genuinely have a parameterless constructor. (Currently you need an instance of `Calc` in order to create an instance of `Gui`, because it's an inner class.)